# Python: I have a global declaration which I need to call in different Python programs

Tags: python

Now, I would like to use `TOPOLOGY` in many scripts. Instead of writing that 
again and again, I would like to keep those in a function or something so 
that I can call them and use them instead of writing again and again in all scripts.

Could you please suggest some better and good solutions?

```
TOPOLOGY = """
[type=switch name="Switch 1"] ops1
[type=host name="Host 1" image="Ubuntu"] hs1
[type=host name="Host 2" image="Ubuntu"] hs2
# Links
hs1:1 -- ops1:1
ops1:2 -- hs2:1
"""

def topology_1switch_2host(topology):
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place your constants in a module and import it from your script:

module constants: (constants.py)

```
""" 
This module contains the constants 
constants.py
"""

# a constants useful in topology
TOPOLOGY = """
[type=switch name="Switch 1"] ops1
[type=host name="Host 1" image="Ubuntu"] hs1
[type=host name="Host 2" image="Ubuntu"] hs2
# Links
hs1:1 -- ops1:1
ops1:2 -- hs2:1
"""
```

Import the constants in your script:

```
""" 
This module contains my script that uses constants 
myscript.py
"""


from constants import TOPOLOGY


def topology_1switch_2host():
    """uses the constant TOPOLOGY
    """
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thank you. will try that

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a class and add the variable as an attribute of the class.

```
Class Topo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Topo = """..."""

    def topology_1switch_2host(self):
        Topology = self.Topo
```

If your list of constants becomes long enough, it might make sense to pickle or json.